# Sorting an array in React after every click issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

I'd like to show a variable size array shuffled with images on it. The problem is the array shuffled all the times when I click on a card. I'd like that the array is going to be shuffled just once before the game not after every click on it.

```
<div className="card-container">
          {deck
            .slice(0, numberOfCards * 2)
            .map((card, index) => (
              <div className="card" onClick={() => cardClicked(index)}>
                <img
                  src={"/images/cards/" + card.image}
                  alt={card.name}
                  className={
                    activeCards.indexOf(index) !== -1 ? "show" : "hide"
                  }
                />
              </div>
            ))
            .sort((a, b) => Math.random() - 0.5)}
        </div>
```

Comment: don't forget to add a `key` to your card div

Comment: And move `.sort((a, b) => Math.random() - 0.5)}` into it's own function, using that returned value for the initial data, instead of calling it on every UI update

Comment: If you could share the `deck` data, or provide a runnable snippet / pen, then it will be easier to demonstrate the solution

Answer (score 1):

assuming that you deck is a state in the component you can do something like this

```
const [deck, setDeck] = useState(props.deck)


useEffect(() => {
  setDeck(deck => [...deck].sort((a, b) => Math.random() - 0.5))
}, [])


return <div className="card-container">
          {deck
            .slice(0, numberOfCards * 2)
            .map((card, index) => (
              <div key={index} className="card" onClick={() => cardClicked(index)}>
                <img
                  src={"/images/cards/" + card.image}
                  alt={card.name}
                  className={
                    activeCards.indexOf(index) !== -1 ? "show" : "hide"
                  }
                />
              </div>
            ))
            }
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's reshuffeled every time because you don't persist the shuffled state and it reruns the logic on every render.

You might want to store a list of image names, or whatever is appropriate in a state variable and rely on that to dictate the order.

```
const [data, setData] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  // your shuffle logic
  // setData()
}, [])
```

then map over the data object. Don't forget the `key` prop